# Error: invalid_client The OAuth client was not found for YouTube Analytics App Script Add on

Tags: javascript

```
var AUTHORIZE_URL = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth'; //step 1. we can actually start directly here if that is necessary
var TOKEN_URL = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'; //step 2. after we get the callback, go get token

var CLIENT_ID = ScriptProperties.getProperty('787853180530-2792spp2fgs0j7tsc2jph2ur6297tmft.apps.googleusercontent.com');
var CLIENT_SECRET = ScriptProperties.getProperty('V9mZYdRwCgCDsWDF6X2Aju0H');

//PUT YOUR URL HERE -
var REDIRECT_URL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyFabJD1uUo3NNXAVVlFVapCRnJw7dJKBmCF3X9nzhgPmxZbRM/exec';


var oauthTokenPropertyName = 'GOOGLE_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN';
var oauthTokenExpiresPropertyName = 'GOOGLE_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES';
var refreshTokenPropertyName = 'GOOGLE_OAUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN';


function getURLForAuthorization() {
    return AUTHORIZE_URL + '?   response_type=code&client_id=' + CLIENT_ID + '&redirect_uri=' + REDIRECT_URL +
    '&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly&approval_prompt=force&access_type=offline&state=/profile';
}

function getAndStoreAccessToken(code) {
    var parameters = {
        method: 'post',
        payload: 'client_id=' + CLIENT_ID + '&client_secret=' + CLIENT_SECRET + '&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=' + REDIRECT_URL + '&code=' + code
    };

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(TOKEN_URL, parameters).getContentText();
    storeOAuthValues_(response);
}

function getUrlFetchOptions() {
    var token = UserProperties.getProperty(oauthTokenPropertyName);
    return {
        "contentType": "application/json",
        "headers": {
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
            "Accept": "application/json"
        }
    };
}

function attemptTokenRefresh_() {
    var refreshToken = UserProperties.getProperty(refreshTokenPropertyName);
    if (!refreshToken) {
        Logger.log('No refresh token available to refresh with ' + refreshTokenPropertyName);
        return false;
    }
    var requestData = {
        method: 'post',
        payload: {
            client_id: CLIENT_ID,
            client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
            refresh_token: refreshToken,
            grant_type: 'refresh_token'
        }
    };
    Logger.log('Attempting token refresh');
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(TOKEN_URL, requestData).getContentText();
    storeOAuthValues_(response);
    return true;
}

function storeOAuthValues_(response) {
    var tokenResponse = JSON.parse(response);

    var accessToken = tokenResponse.access_token;
    // expires_in is in seconds and Date.now is ms
    var endMs = Date.now() + tokenResponse.expires_in * 1000;
    var refreshToken = tokenResponse.refresh_token;

    //store the token for later retrieval
    UserProperties.setProperty(oauthTokenPropertyName, accessToken);
    if (refreshToken) { //on a refresh call we wont get a new refresh token,   lets not wipe prev one out
        UserProperties.setProperty(refreshTokenPropertyName, refreshToken);
    }
    UserProperties.setProperty(oauthTokenExpiresPropertyName, endMs);
}

function isOAuthed() {
    if (hasValidToken_()) {
        Logger.log('Valid oauth token found');
        return true;
    } else {
        try {
            return attemptTokenRefresh_();
        } catch (e) {
            Logger.log('Failed to refresh token with error: ' + e);
            return false;
        }
    }
}

function hasValidToken_() {
    if (!isTokenPresent_()) {
        return false;
    }
    return (!isTokenExpired_());
}

function isTokenExpired_() {
    var expirationTimeMs = UserProperties.getProperty(oauthTokenExpiresPropertyName);
    if (!expirationTimeMs) {
        return true;
    }
    expirationTimeMs = Number(expirationTimeMs);
    var threshold = Date.now() + 30000;
    return (expirationTimeMs < threshold);
}

function isTokenPresent_() {
    var token = UserProperties.getProperty(oauthTokenPropertyName);
    if (!token) { //if its empty or undefined
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

google developer https://console.developers.google.com/project -> project name select -> APIs&Auth -> credential 
enter mail adres

Comment: You've outlined some steps here but it's unclear what they do. If you include some explanation, this could be a valuable answer.